# VBA/Conditional Formatting based on a formula

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

For both of these I'd prefer VBA however conditional formatting would be fine.

1:
I need vba/conditional formatting to format my table A:F the following ways:

Essentially:
I need a top border if Cell A2 & A1 are not the same
I need a top and bottom border is Cell A2 & A1 are not the same AND Cell A2 & A3 are not the same
I need a bottom border if Cell A2 & A3 are not the same

Conditional Formatting

[image: 3]

Sadly this is doing nothing and I've no clue why

2:
I'd need vba/conditional formatting to fill cell a:f with specific text (different per column) if specific text is in column b of the row.

My example is in formula mode but I know that doesn't fit directly into vba or conditional formatting:

In Cell B105
=IF(A105="ETSY",B1,0)

The desired effect is that cell B105 returns the value that is in B1, and so on for C105 reading the value from C1, all along to cell F.
But only if the value in that row A is specifically "ETSY"

Along with this as it's probably easier to include at the same time (maybe). I'd like this row to be formatted bold too.

Conditional Formatting

[image: 4]

EDIT:

It's adding the lines in the wrong places.

It should look like this:
[image: RIGHT]

But it looks like this:
[image: WRONG]

Comment: You have to remove the $ from the row references: e.g. `=$A1 <> $A2` - otherwise only this row is checked.

Comment: Please see edit where i've added images, that is allowing it to work but it's not working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the borders you will need only one conditional formula: When the Value of a cell (of column A) is different from the cell *below*, put a (bottom) borders to that cell. As you want to put the border to the whole row (from col A to F) depending on the value in cell A, you put the dollar sign to the column character. So the formula looks simply like

```
=$A1<>$A2
```

Note that (at least on your screenshot), you have quotes around the formula. They are sometimes added by Excel. If this is the case, remove them.

Conditional formatting for rows where column A is "Etsy" is very similar, the formula for this would be

```
=$A1="ETSY"
```

Again, after entering it, check if Excel added quotes around the whole formula.

---

Now filling cells in column B..F if column A contains "ETSY" cannot be achieved with a formula - simply because a cell cannot contain a value *and* a formula. If you use a formula like `=IF(A105="ETSY",B1,0)`, you would end up with 0 in any cell where the value in column A is *not* "ETSY" - and the original content is gone. You could write some VBA code for that, but that's a different topic. Your question was about conditional formatting and there is a rule (for a good reason) on SO that a question should contain only one question, not multiple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following macro to get similar effect. Macro defines conditional formatting with different text for different columns. To make it work as expected there must be any numbers in the formatted area.

```
Sub FormatCond()
    Dim c As Range, header As String, rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("B2:C7")    'range to format
    rng.FormatConditions.Delete
    For Each c In rng.Columns
       c.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A2=""ETSY"""
       c.FormatConditions(1).Font.Bold = True
       header = Cells(1, c.Column).Value   ' first row
       c.FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = Chr(34) & header & Chr(34)
    Next c
End Sub
```

[image: Cond_Format_Headers]